# Is PrinterUri attribute ignored by Java PrintService?

Tags: java, attributes, postscript, printers, ipp-protocol

I'm using the following code in order to send a print job to a specific printer:

```
PrintServiceAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintServiceAttributeSet();
     try {
            aset.add(new PrinterURI(new URI("ipp://hostName/printerName")));
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            System.out.println("URI exception caught: "+e);
        }
        PrintService[] services =
            PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.POSTSCRIPT,aset);
```

Strangley, I get 9 lookup results (=all available printers on that specific host) - while only the first result is the one I'm seeking.
I searched in the PrintService JavaDocs, and on the web - but found nothing on the matter.

Isn't PrintServiceLookup expected to return only the printers which match my request? (in this case - one printer)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Naturally I have a work around for this issue: I search the desired printer within the results. However, I still don't understand how come I get more than 1 answer. I tested the very same code with `DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.POSTSCRIPT` but **without** the `PrinterUri` attribute and got the same 9 results - it appears that the `PrintServiceAttributeSet` is being ignored...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the URI I was using was wrong (yet with a valid syntax, so no exception was thrown).
So answering my initial question - Java PrintService ignores an attribute which is wrong (as opposed to my expectation, that PrintService would return no result in case of a wrong attribute).

Thanks anyway

Comment: how is the correct ipp: format, i cant access to a priner like \\PSCPARKP01\CP_P1_OKI20_2